# I was not able to insert data(which is declared by set) into day partitioned table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table which is partitioned by day .I tried inserting the data by setting

## set hivevar:ds=2018-12-01;

then using ** INSERT OVERWRITE table XTABLE partition(day='${hivevar:ds}') **
which is working fine

but when i do like below

## set hivevar:pd=date_add('${hivevar:ds}',-1);

then ** INSERT OVERWRITE table XTABLE partition(day='${hivevar:pd}') **
it is throwing error. i think problem is because of extra quotes but not able to find how to solve.

error is :

## cannot recognize input near ''date_add('' '2018' '-' in constant

MYCODE:

---

```
set hivevar:ds=2018-12-01;
set hivevar:pd=date_add('${hivevar:ds}',-1);
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS XTABLE (emp_id BIGINT, start_time STRING, end_time STRING)
PARTITIONED BY(day STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';


--THIS IS WORKING FINE
INSERT OVERWRITE table XTABLE partition(day='${hivevar:ds}')
select distinct d.emp_id, d.start_time, d.end_time from
(
select emp_id, start_time, end_time from XTABLE where day='${hivevar:ds}'
) d;


--THIS IS THROWING AN ERROR cannot recognize input near ''date_add('' '2018' '-' in constant
--SEEMS PROBLEM IS WHILE SETTING THE VARIABLE
INSERT OVERWRITE table XTABLE partition(day='${hivevar:pd}')
select distinct d.emp_id, d.start_time, d.end_time from
(
select emp_id, start_time, end_time from XTABLE where day='${hivevar:pd}'
) d;
```

---

if success it should give message like below:

Loading data to table xtable partition (day=2018-12-01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are trying to insert using static partition with function in it's specification. You can use dynamic partition insert, providing partition in the dataset:

```
set hivevar:ds=2018-12-01;

set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

INSERT OVERWRITE table XTABLE partition(day)
select distinct d.emp_id, d.start_time, d.end_time from
(
select emp_id, start_time, end_time, day --partition present in dataset, also it can be date_sub('${hivevar:ds}',1) as day
from XTABLE where day=date_sub('${hivevar:ds}',1);
) d;
```

This will work, but it may cause table full scan because partition pruning does not work with functions. So, the best solution is to calculate date-1 day in the shell and pass it as a parameter inside HQL script:

```
ds=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date " -1 day")

hive --hiveconf ds="$ds" -f your_script.hql
```

And inside your script use `'${hiveconf:ds}'`

Comment: Thanks for responding @leftjoin .But i want to run the query from hive command shell.

Comment: @saicharan then use first script in my answer

Comment: as you suggested i used this .    **set hivevar:ds=2018-12-01;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
INSERT OVERWRITE table XTABLE partition(day)
select distinct d.emp_id, d.start_time, d.end_time,d.day from
(
select emp_id, start_time, end_time, date_sub('${hivevar:ds}',1) as day --partition present in dataset, also it can be date_sub('${hivevar:ds}',1) as day
from XTABLE where day=date_sub('${hivevar:ds}',1)
) d;**  but it is giving this message. Loading data to table xtable partition (day=null). day shouldnot be null there

Comment: check what this returns:  set hivevar:ds=2018-12-01;  select  date_sub('${hivevar:ds}',1);

Comment: can it be that you just did not execute set hivevar:ds=2018-12-01; previously? And check also what the whole select without insert returns

Answer (score 1):

@saicharan You cannot add a function while setting a variable. 
I had faced a similar issue.

set hivevar:ds='should always have a static value'

To solve this issue, you need to create a simple script as below:

```
ds=`date -d "+1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d"`
echo $ds

hive --hivevar ds="${ds}" -e "INSERT OVERWRITE table XTABLE partition(day='${hivevar:ds}') "
```

This should solve your problem. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Sagar Morakhia .This is working but i want this to be done completely from the hive command shell